# save image to mysql database using php

Tags: php

I am trying to do upload my images to mysql database,i use this code for that.i have three table value id,name and image.

```html
<html>
<body>
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><br/>
<input type="file" name="image" /><br/><br/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" /><br/><br/> 
</form>

<?php

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE)
   {
   echo "plese select an image";
   }
   else{
    $image=addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
 $image=file_get_contents($image);
 $image=base64_encode($image);
 saveimage($name,$image);
 
   }
   }
  
   function saveimage()
   {
   $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("test",$con);
   $qry="insert into images(name,image) values('$name','$image')";
   $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
   
   if($result)
   {
   echo "<br/> Image upload";
   }
   else
   {
    echo "<br/> Image not upload";
   }
   }
 
   //mysql_close($con);
 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

when i upload image it will show

Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\img\picinsert.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined variable: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\img\picinsert.php on line 32

Image upload
but when i check the table no image upload it..

Comment: First things first I would avoid even starting code with `mysql` functions as PHP7 has removed them. Try `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: it's not work for me.

Comment: That wasn't a fix for your problem, more just a helpful reminder to help future-proof your code.

Answer (score 0):

First that cannot work because in your function prototype you didn't insert the possible variable wich probably are image and name.

```
function saveimage($name, $image) //this should work :)
```

Or if you don't want use this technic, you have to use the global variable.
Example:

```
$var = 5;
function showvar()
{ 
   echo $GLOBALS['var'];

}
showvar(); //5 will be displayed
```

Try that and give news :)

Comment: Set the question as answered please :)